# Why i am not able to use the typedef with function pointer

Tags: function, function-pointers, typedef

Why its not working. Please bear with me, i am beginner

```
#include <stdio.h>
int fun(int a)
{
  printf("Value of a is %d\n", a);
  return a;
}

int main()
{

  typedef int (*fun_ptr)(int);



  fun_ptr * ptr = &fun;


  int h = (*ptr)(10);

  return 0;
}
```

I am trying to learn function pointer with typedef